# Specifying icecast protocol options in ffmpeg/avconv on Raspbian Lite

Tags: ffmpeg, raspberry-pi, raspbian, libav

I'm very new at this Raspberry Pi 3 thing, but not afraid to delve into docs and examples. I've cobbled together commands and fixes to record audio from USB device - ultimately trying to stream directly from card to my Icecast server.

For now I'm just trying to find out if I can connect to my Icecast server with the current avconv program - just playing a small local mp3 file. At this point I'm trying to use the Lite version of Raspbian - without having to rebuild ffmpeg.

I'm trying to use icecast protocol options with installed version of avconv on Raspbian (4.9.2-10)

> avconv version is listed as 11.7.6:11.7-1
>
> libavutil 54. 3. 0

Basically I need to submit the options `ice_name` and `ice_description`, as well as stream `password` via icecast protocol options. Using `avconv`, it appears that I can send an mp3 file to the icecast stream with no errors, but nothing shows up on other end.

One issue may be I have to submit password without username - so that might not work with a null username in the url. That said I haven't seen any error submitting as `icecast://:mypwd@icecast.myserver.com`

I also need to submit the stream name

It doesn't appear that my avconv version supports the `Icecast protocol options`. In theory you can specify `ice_name` `password` `ice_description` `ice_public`

This is what I tried without error (but no broadcast):

```
avconv -re -i test.mp3 -b:a 128k -legacy_icecast 1 -f mp3 icecast://:mypwd@icecast.my-ic-server.com:443/my-mount-point/url-here
```

If I try to add the ice_name protocol option,

```
avconv -re -i test.mp3 -b:a 128k -legacy_icecast 1 -ice_name "My Raspi Stream" -f mp3 icecast://:mypwd@icecast.my-ic-server.com:443/my-mount-point/url-here
```

it just creates a new filename called

> ice_name "My Raspi Stream"

Any help, suggestions or references much appreciated.
I may start the manual compile of ffmpeg in meantime

Answer (score 0):

I did get this to work using avconv so I now know it is possible to use avconv as is. It is required to use the `-legacy_icecast 1` parameter, even if your server is Icecast 2

Minimum I needed to get it to work:

```
avconv -re -i test.mp3 -c:a libmp3lame -content_type audio/mpeg -b:a 128k -legacy_icecast 1 -ice_name "Raspi Test Stream of MP3" -password mypwd -f mp3 icecast://icecast.servername.com/my/mount/point/url
```

Next up - streaming live... by the way I'm using the Spreaker.com site, if anyone is interested - but it should work with any icecast server